# The volt-time constant of a pulse transformer

Tags: transformer, insulation

I am looking for a transformer to use with a RS485 driver, but I don't know to which criterium I should pay more attention: insulation voltage or volt-time constant.

Can someone explain to me if the volt-time product is representative of a good pulse transformer used for isolation purposes?

If yes, how does this constant influence the quality of the transformer? The bigger the better or the smaller the better?

Or does only the insulation voltage matter?

Comment: At what protocol, line encoding and data rate this will be used? Because it depends on how long pulses the transformer has to pass without degrading the signal. Generally RS-485 interfaces are not transformer isolated, but for special cases they can be. Also an isolated RS-485 interface can be built without a transformer on data path, if the signal bandwidth must work down to DC.

Comment: A big industrial mfr made a product which used 330Vµs GPT's as isolated power transformers at 10MHz.  They ran HOT and these failed higher than average... I found that replacing them with 450Vµs GPT's ran much cooler.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain to me if the volt-time product is representative of a good pulse transformer used for isolation purposes?

Voltage*time / volt-microsecond / ET product can be thought of in practical terms like this: `9.1` means you can apply 9.1V across the primary winding of the transformer for `1μsec` before the core saturates.  Or `1V` for `9.1μsec`.  In other words, it's how much "magnetic flux storage capability" the transformer has.

As for isolation purposes, ET is just a specification for maximum core saturation. As long as the ET value is not repeatedly/continuously exceeded (such as by sending too long/continuous pulse) it will continue operating normally.  When ET *is* exceeded, the core will heat up and eventually fail (possibly in a fire.)

For RS485 in particular, if the transmissions are not continuous, then DC-blocking capacitors may have to be added in series.

To spec ET, take the longest pulse duration that will be sent to the transformer (in µs) and multiply it by the applied voltage.

```
Example: 50kHz PWM, 90% duty, 5V.  
50kHz is 20µs, and 90% of that is 18µs. 
18µs*5V = ET of 90 minimum.
```

> If yes, how does this constant influence the quality of the transformer? The bigger the better or the smaller the better?

This is an X/Y question.

The bigger the ET, the *more* magnetic flux can be stored, which usually equates to *increased size*. It could also mean that higher ET uses a higher-saturating core material (and likely bigger windings for lower losses.)

Bottom line is, *a higher ET transformer can be used (and it will run cooler) but will be more expensive and larger than needed.*

> Or does only the insulation voltage matter?

Insulation withstanding voltage should be considered separately.

If the 90Vµs transformer above were being used in a home setting (nothing notable electrically) then 1kV isolation may be fine.  But if used in an industrial or medical application, may want to go much higher; 4kV or more.  Of course higher isolation rating will be larger and cost more.

If you're trying to communicate RS485 to a twenty-foot-tall Marx generator... well forget transformers and totally go the fiber-optic route.

Comment: I guess your 9.1 ET pulse transformer is much smaller than my 10 kV 4.5 us pulse transformer

Answer (score 0):

The volt-second time constant gives an indication of the lowest frequency that can be passed without saturating the core of the transformer. The primary winding has inductance that magnetizes the core and if the product of voltage and time is too great the magnetic flux in the core reaches a level of saturation where problems occur. Those problems can be distortion of the output signal or overheating.

Power transformers tend to have a big volt-second constant to be able to deal with low power frequencies (50 or 60 Hz) at high input voltages (typically 100 to 300 VRMS). This makes them physically larger than an equivalently powerful transformer used in a switch mode power supply operating at (say) 100 kHz. This is because the primary inductance of a regular power transformer has to be in the order of 1 henry or above. That needs a lot of turns and makes the device physically larger.

For a pulse transformer, the main criteria is isolation and the ability to transmit a decent shaped signal (typically a square wave of limited amplitude, maybe 10 or 20 Vp-p) of a frequency that is usually greater than 10 kHz. This means that its primary inductance can be very much smaller than a power transformer and hence, its physical size is small.